# Mi html tiene un espacio en blanco abajo

Tags: html5, angular, typescript, scss

Hola buenas debido a la naturaleza de mi pregunta creo que el problema se puede entender mejor con imágenes que con código, yo tan solo espero que si alguien conoce la respuesta como algo que se haga de forma habitual me pueda dar una solución o un tip, no puedo colocar aquí el código html por que es muy largo y esta generado con Angular.

Sin embargo con dos imágenes se entenderá perfectamente:

Microsoft Edge:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

FireFox:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese espacio en blanco lo podria quitar cambiando el height de mis contenedores pero si modifico mi layout para que se vea bien en un navegador se ve mal en el otro no se como hacer que se vea bien en todos.

Ya probe usando height:100% en mis contenedores pero pasan cosas muy raras y no se resuelve el problema.

Por aqui también he visto la solución de poner el footer en fixed pero no me gusta para nada como queda, la solución que se me ocurre es poner todo en general del color del footer y darle un background-color ha cada una de mis cajas pero esa solución tampoco me gusta mucho.

Pero aun asi sigo sin entender porque esta ese espacio en blanco.

Código de scss principal:

```
/** ***************** GENERALES ******************* **/

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    color: #aaa;
    height: 100%;

    ul {
        display: flex;

        li {

            display: flex;
            margin-left: 2rem;
            margin-right: 2rem;
        }
    }

    a {

        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #383838
    }

    p {

        font-size: 15px;

    }

    label {

        font-size: 17px;

    }

    input {

        font-size: 17px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 0;

    }

    button {

        font-size: 17px;
        color: white;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #412e8bd6;
        width: 90px;
        height: 40px;

    }

    button:hover{

        background-color: #b4a8e8d6;
        transition: background-color 120ms;
    }

}

.container {

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 669px;

    h2 {

        margin: 20px;

    }
}


/** ***************** CABECERA ******************* **/

.header {

    grid-area: header;
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    position: fixed;
    height: 58px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;

}

/** ***************** CONTENIDO ******************* **/

.main-content {

    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;

}


/** ***************** PIE DE PÁGINA ******************* **/

.footer {

    position:relative;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: 30px solid #1a1a1a ;
    border-bottom: 45px solid #1a1a1a;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 2%;

}
```

scss del nav

```
.content-nav {

    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;

    .return {

        display: flex;
        align-self: center;
        width: auto;
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-top: 5px;

        #main-icon {

            fill: #383838
        }
    }

    .menu-wrapper {

        display: flex;
        justify-content: right;
        width: 575px;

        ul {

            li {

                a:hover {

                    color: #00b8d4;
                    transition: color 120ms;

                }
            }
        }
    }

    .social-media {

        margin-right: 80px;

        #linkedin-icon {

            fill: #383838;
        }

        #github-icon {

            fill: #383838;

        }

        .selected {

            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            border-radius: 100%;
            transition: background-color 300ms;

        }

        .selected:hover {

            background-color: rgb(0, 184, 212);
            transition: background-color 300ms;

        }
    }
}
```

html de prueba

```
<header class="header">
    <nav class="content-nav">
        <div class="return">
        </div>
        <div class="menu-wrapper">
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['/sobre-mi']">Sobre mi</a></li>
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['/proyectos']">Proyectos</a></li>
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['/']">Página principal</a></li>
                    <li><a *ngIf="hide" [routerLink]="['/crear-proyecto']">Añadir proyecto</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="social-media">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="selected"
                        href="https://es.linkedin.com/in/daniel-berroteran?original_referer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.es%2F"
                        target="_blank">
                        <svg id=linkedin-icon viewBox="0 0 30 30" width="25px" height="30px">
                            <path
                                d="M9,25H4V10h5V25z M6.501,8C5.118,8,4,6.879,4,5.499S5.12,3,6.501,3C7.879,3,9,4.121,9,5.499C9,6.879,7.879,8,6.501,8z M27,25h-4.807v-7.3c0-1.741-0.033-3.98-2.499-3.98c-2.503,0-2.888,1.896-2.888,3.854V25H12V9.989h4.614v2.051h0.065 c0.642-1.18,2.211-2.424,4.551-2.424c4.87,0,5.77,3.109,5.77,7.151C27,16.767,27,25,27,25z" />
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li><a class="selected" href="https://github.com/search?q=danielbn64" target="_blank">
                        <svg id="github-icon" width="20" height="24" viewBox="0 1 25 20">
                            <path
                                d="M12 0c-6.626 0-12 5.373-12 12 0 5.302 3.438 9.8 8.207 11.387.599.111.793-.261.793-.577v-2.234c-3.338.726-4.033-1.416-4.033-1.416-.546-1.387-1.333-1.756-1.333-1.756-1.089-.745.083-.729.083-.729 1.205.084 1.839 1.237 1.839 1.237 1.07 1.834 2.807 1.304 3.492.997.107-.775.418-1.305.762-1.604-2.665-.305-5.467-1.334-5.467-5.931 0-1.311.469-2.381 1.236-3.221-.124-.303-.535-1.524.117-3.176 0 0 1.008-.322 3.301 1.23.957-.266 1.983-.399 3.003-.404 1.02.005 2.047.138 3.006.404 2.291-1.552 3.297-1.23 3.297-1.23.653 1.653.242 2.874.118 3.176.77.84 1.235 1.911 1.235 3.221 0 4.609-2.807 5.624-5.479 5.921.43.372.823 1.102.823 2.222v3.293c0 .319.192.694.801.576 4.765-1.589 8.199-6.086 8.199-11.386 0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12z" />
                        </svg>
                    </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <div *ngIf="project">
        <div *ngIf="status == 'success'" class="success">
            El proyecto se a creado correctamente puedes verlo
            <a [routerLink]="['/proyecto',savedProject._id]">aquí</a>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="status == 'failed'" class="failed">
            El proyecto no se ha podido crear
        </div>
        <div class="form-wrapper">
            <form class="form-create" #projectForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(projectForm)">
                <div class="form-create-one">
                    <div>
                        <label for="name">
                            <h4>Nombre</h4>
                        </label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="name" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="project.name" required />
                        <p>
                            <span *ngIf="name.touched && !name.valid">
                                El nombre es obligatorio
                            </span><br />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="category">
                            <h4>Categoria</h4>
                        </label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="category" #category="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="project.category"
                            required />
                        <p>
                            <span *ngIf="category.touched && !category.valid">
                                La categoria es obligatorio
                            </span><br />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="year">
                            <h4>Año de lanzamiento</h4>
                        </label><br />
                        <input type="number" name="year" #year="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="project.year" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="languages">
                            <h4>Lenguajes utilizados</h4>
                        </label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="languages" #languages="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="project.languages"
                            required />
                        <p>
                            <span *ngIf="languages.touched && !languages.valid">
                                Los lenguajes son<br /> obligatorios
                            </span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-create-two">
                    <div>
                        <label for="description">
                            <h4>Descripción</h4>
                        </label><br />
                        <textarea name="description" #description="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="project.description" required>
                        </textarea><br />
                        <p>
                            <span *ngIf="description.touched && !description.valid">
                                La descripción es obligatoria
                            </span><br />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="image">
                            <h4>Imagen del proyecto</h4>
                        </label>
                        <div *ngIf="project.image">
                            <img class="image" src="{{url+'get-image/'+project.image}}" *ngIf="project.image" />
                        </div>
                        <input (change)="getFile($event)" type="file" name="image" placeholder="Subir imagen">
                    </div>
                    <div class="button-end">
                        <button type="submit" value="Enviar" [disabled]="!projectForm.form.valid">
                            Crear
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
    Daniel Berroterán &copy;
</footer>
```

Mi proyecto esta en:
https://github.com/Danielbn64/proyecto.portafolio-parastovflw

Comment: Y si mejor pones el código html y css?

Comment: Puedo poner el proyecto entero en github para que lo puedas clonar pero la verdad si es mucha molestia :c

Comment: No es necesario que lo subas a GitHub, usa los snippets. Edita y pon el código con el botón que está al lado derecho de el de subir imagen o con Control+M.

Comment: Pero no entiendo porque quieres que ponga el código, el html y css de esta aplicación esta repartido en varios componentes, cada componente tiene su html y su css, ademas yo creo que este problema puede ser tan común que haya una solución generica, mira te voy a pasar el scss de mis estilos generales y de mi app.component pero mas nada si no seria muy pesado.

Comment: Como te han dicho deberías poner el html, con el podríamos tocar y comprobar, la imagen solo podemos ver para ella.

Comment: Para poder probar mi proyecto tendrían que descargar nodejs y mongodb, clonar repositorio crear las bases de datos y quizás alguna cosa mas, repito que mi html no esta en un solo fichero sino en muchos y mi css también y por eso es muy complicado subirlo todo voy a pasar el enlace a github para quien quiera probarlo pero la configuración para poder probar la aplicación es un poco larga.

Comment: El problema está en body{height: 100%;}
Borra esa linea y estará resuelto.

Comment: Hola Espulito no me a resuelto el problema si quieres ayudarme puedes clonar mi repositorio, deje el enlace en la pregunta

Comment: Ya subí el repositorio para quien quiera mirar a ver que me cuenta

Comment: Pero es que no tienes que subir el repositorio, con que pongas aquí una o dos páginas HTML de ejemplo llega. ¿La pregunta de que es: de HTML, de php o de que otro lenguaje?  por favor, lee la ayuda antes de preguntar de nuevo https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Perdón ya he corregido mi pregunta y he puesto las etiquetas correctas, el html es de un proyecto hecho con Angular.

Comment: Genial, ahora si pegas el HTMl ya estaremos más cerca de poder ayudarte ;)

Answer (score -1):

Hola buenas gracias por prestar atención a mi pregunta, quiero decir que no encontré ninguna solución para eliminar ese espacio en blanco debajo de la página sin tocar las dimensiones de mis cajas lo que he hecho es aumentar el tamaño del footer aunque eso me provocara scroll hacia abajo y asi ocupara el espacio en blanco, esa pequeña solución estéticamente no se ve mal.

Esta pregunta como muchas no es un error de código realmente si no mas bien aspectos a tomar encuenta en la maquetación, ya que uno puede estar trabajando un diseño ajustado para Chrome pero luego se ve mal en Firefox, moraleja probar el diseño en distintos navegadores para ver como lo interpreta.

```
.footer {
    
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    width: 100%;
    height: 320px;

}
```

Comment: Discrepo en tu comentario, si que tienes "un error de código" y deberías investigar lo que sucede, porque sino vas a ir añadiendo problemas al proyecto. Una vez descubras cual es el problema ya decidirás de que forma arreglarlo o si lo quieres dejar así. Empieza por quitar contenido, hasta que descubras cual es la css problemática, una vez aislado (con el contenido mínimo) te será más fácil encontrar una solución. Si escondes el problema entonces tendrás 2 problemas ;)